# Join two queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to join these two queries on:

InventoryItemID and can't seem to make it work.  I have tried a number of solutions, but can't wrap my head around it.  I am using Microsoft SQL.

```
select t1.itemcode, t1.Description, t1.MinimumQuantity, t1.QuantityInStore, t2.qty as OnOrder, t1.InventoryItemID
from
    (
select i.InventoryItemID,  i.ItemCode, i.Description, MinimumQuantity, ii.QuantityInStore
    from InventoryInfo i
    inner join InventoryStoreInfo ii
        on i.InventoryItemID = ii.inventoryitemid
    inner join PurchaseOrderItemInfo p
        on ii.InventoryItemID = p.InventoryItemID
    inner join PurchaseOrderInfo po
        on p.PurchaseOrderID = po.PurchaseOrderID
    inner join VendorInfo v
        on po.VendorID = v.VendorID
    where InventoryCategoryID = '1'
    and i.IsActive = '1'
    ) as t1
left join 
    (
select InventoryItemID, sum(Quantity) as QTY, Description
    from PurchaseOrderItemInfo p
    inner join PurchaseOrderInfo po
        on p.PurchaseOrderID = po.PurchaseOrderID
    where p.status = '0'
    group by InventoryItemID, Description
    ) as t2
on t1.inventoryitemid = t2.inventoryitemid
```

and

```
select pi.InventoryItemID, v.VendorName, max(p.PODateTime) as latest
from PurchaseOrderItemInfo pi
inner join PurchaseOrderInfo p
    on pi.PurchaseOrderID = p.PurchaseOrderID
inner join InventoryInfo i
    on pi.InventoryItemID = i.InventoryItemID
inner join VendorInfo v
    on p.VendorID = v.VendorID
group by pi.inventoryitemid, p.PODateTime,i.description, v.VendorName
order by latest desc
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Are you looking for `select * from (query 1 goes here) q1 JOIN (query 2 goes here) q2 on q1.InventoryItemID = q2.InventoryItemID`

Comment: The two queries that I have provided both have inventoryitemid in common, I want to add the date from Query 2 to Query 1

Comment: I think you can add the second query just like you added t2 select. have you tried that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrap each query between parenthesis to create subquery `(queryA)` and  `(queryB)`

Then assing an alias to each subquery and perfom the join

```
SELECT aliasA.*, aliasB.*
FROM
  (queryA) aliasA
INNER JOIN  (queryB)  aliasB
  ON aliasA.ID =  aliasB.ID
```

USING YOUR QUERY

```
SELECT FIRSTQUERY.*, SECONDQUERY.*
FROM 
    (
    select t1.itemcode, t1.Description, t1.MinimumQuantity, t1.QuantityInStore, t2.qty as OnOrder, t1.InventoryItemID
    from
        (
        select i.InventoryItemID,  i.ItemCode, i.Description, MinimumQuantity, ii.QuantityInStore
        from InventoryInfo i
        inner join InventoryStoreInfo ii
            on i.InventoryItemID = ii.inventoryitemid
        inner join PurchaseOrderItemInfo p
            on ii.InventoryItemID = p.InventoryItemID
        inner join PurchaseOrderInfo po
            on p.PurchaseOrderID = po.PurchaseOrderID
        inner join VendorInfo v
            on po.VendorID = v.VendorID
        where InventoryCategoryID = '1'
        and i.IsActive = '1'
        ) as t1
    left join 
        (
        select InventoryItemID, sum(Quantity) as QTY, Description
        from PurchaseOrderItemInfo p
        inner join PurchaseOrderInfo po
            on p.PurchaseOrderID = po.PurchaseOrderID
        where p.status = '0'
        group by InventoryItemID, Description
        ) as t2
    on t1.inventoryitemid = t2.inventoryitemid
    ) FIRSTQUERY
    INNER JOIN
    (
    select pi.InventoryItemID, v.VendorName, max(p.PODateTime) as latest
    from PurchaseOrderItemInfo pi
    inner join PurchaseOrderInfo p
        on pi.PurchaseOrderID = p.PurchaseOrderID
    inner join InventoryInfo i
        on pi.InventoryItemID = i.InventoryItemID
    inner join VendorInfo v
        on p.VendorID = v.VendorID
    group by pi.inventoryitemid, p.PODateTime,i.description, v.VendorName
    order by latest desc
    ) SECONDQUERY
    ON FIRSTQUERY.InventoryItemID  = SECONDQUERY.InventoryItemID
```